# service call inside loop doesn't stops loop even if condition is false

Tags: angularjs, foreach, asynchronous-javascript

I want to stop repeated call to `getModelData` if `shouldPermit` becomes `true`. But below code always prints `why I got printed forEach newlySelectedUsers` in console for each `newlySelectedUsers`.

```
var shouldPermit = false;
angular.forEach(newlySelectedUsers, function(value, key) {
if(!shouldPermit) { 
console.log("why I got printed forEach newlySelectedUsers")                         
userService.getModelData($scope.$root.test[value].id)
.success(function (data) {                                
    if(lodash.isEmpty(data)) {                                      
        shouldPermit = true;
        $scope.insertSaving();
     }
       });                           
         }                      
          });
```

How to stop calls to `getModelData` once `shouldPermit` becomes true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because **all the http requests run asynchronusly**. That beeing said your itteration runs faster than the time needed for service to find (in your case) an empty data variable .

An option is to **recursively** call the http request:

```
const totalNewlySelectedUsers = newlySelectedUsers.length;


function getUser(idx) {

    let value = newlySelectedUsers[idx];

    userService.getModelData($scope.$root.test[value].id)
        .success(function (data) {
            if (lodash.isEmpty(data))
                $scope.insertSaving();
                return;
            }

            if(idx === totalNewlySelectedUsers) return;

            getUser(idx + 1);
        });

}

getUser(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Asynchronous. The second iteration doesn't wait for `userService.getModelData()` called for first iteration to finish. So, you get console message even before it goes the success function of first iteration's `userService.getModelData()` where you change the `shouldPermit` to true.

Instead, you just move `shouldPermit = true;` to top to solve the issue.

```
var shouldPermit = false;
angular.forEach(newlySelectedUsers, function(value, key) {
if(!shouldPermit) 
{ 
  console.log("why I got printed forEach newlySelectedUsers");
  shouldPermit = true; <--- Moved from success function                  
  userService.getModelData($scope.$root.test[value].id) <--- Async Call
  .success(function (data) {                                
    if(lodash.isEmpty(data)) 
    {                                      
        $scope.insertSaving();
     }
     });                           
     }                      
   });
```

Comment: shouldPermit should be set to true only if data is empty. So we can't put it outside the condition to solve the issue.